# cakephp remove https at localhost

Tags: php, https, cakephp-2.0

**im working with cakephp 2.x..
some of my page cannot display in localhost, they give me "An Internal Error Has Occurred."
but when i run in server there is no problem at all..**

when evrytime i start my localhost page then it come out the "website's security certificate."

i think the problem is permission from https..
how can i remove the https or get the certificate or anything that can fix this..

i hope somebody can help me with this..thanks..

Comment: by "but when i run in server there is no problem at all..", do you mean running the same code from command line?  Check your web server logs, those 500 errors might have left more information there.

Comment: @ficuscr  yess..im running the same code..where can i find 500 errors??
what should i do with them??

Answer (score 0):

when your computer time is not set correctly then it shows `website's security certificate.`